# What happens when weeping trees touch the ground? (Should it be fixed?)

Tags: tree-care

I let some of my weeping trees grow as they wish. My neighbor says I should prune them the so that their branches do not touch the ground. He could not say why, just says it is bad for branches to touch the ground. Does that make sense? The trees in question, if this is for any reason important, are Caragana arborescens 'Pendula' and Morus alba 'Pendula'.